# Opencv stitching images result error

Tags: opencv

I make `Image Stitcher` which merge 10 images(or more).

Merging images seems right, but this result has some problem. The result is not drawing perfectly, It has black area.

This is output

[image]

Why this problem is occurred? When i run this program, it uses a lot of cpu and memory, is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ucQO.png) related to the problem?

+)The images used to merge is 2880*2880

+)This is my code

```
QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    QUrl url(id);
    QString file = url.toLocalFile();
    QString queryStr = url.query();
    QUrlQuery query(queryStr);

    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(true);
    stitcher.setFeaturesFinder(makePtr<detail::SurfFeaturesFinder>(100));

    vector<Mat> imgs;
    foreach (auto node, query.queryItems()) {
        if(node.first == "src") {
            imgs.push_back(cv::imread(node.second.remove(0,7).toStdString()));
        } else if(node.first == "hessian") {
            //stitcher.setFeaturesFinder(makePtr<detail::SurfFeaturesFinder>(node.second.toInt()));
            stitcher.setFeaturesFinder(makePtr<detail::SurfFeaturesFinder>(100));  
        }
    }
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);
    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << status << endl;
        return QImage();
    }
    return cvMatToQImage(pano);

}
```

+) I try reducing image `size(2880*2880->256*256)` but `Stitcher` occur same problem.

Comment: Please add some code. What excatly is the problem? what is the result you are expecting?
If you think there is a problem with the image size, try reducing them.

Comment: I edit this post, i tried reducing image size but same error is occurred..